# multiplying columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame like this.

```
> abc
   ID 1.x 2.x 1.y 2.y
1   4  10  20  30  40
2  16   5  10   5  10
3  42  16  17  18  19
4  91  20  20  20  20
5 103 103  42  56  84
```

How do I create two additional columns '1' and '2' by multiplying 1.x * 1.y and 2.x * 2.y in a generalized way?

I am trying to get a generalized solution where number of columns can be too many. So I want to multiply all x with all y. While x and y are fixed, n has to be figured out from data frame.

For simplicity lets assume n is also fixed however it is a large number.

One thing i can try is :-

`abc[,c(6,7)]=abc[,c(2,3)]*abc[,c(4,5)]` 
It will work only if col positions are contiguous. This is good enough for me. If anyone can have more generalized solution, it will benefit us all.

Comment: Will the names always have the structure where the only difference is the number and then either `x` or `y`?

Comment: yes names have structure , we may assume x and y are fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are only couple of variables to multiply, we can do this with `transform` by multiplying the columns of interest

```
transform(abc, new1 = `1.x`*`1.y`, new2 = `2.x`*`2.y`, check.names = FALSE)
#   ID 1.x 2.x 1.y 2.y new1 new2
#1   4  10  20  30  40  300  800
#2  16   5  10   5  10   25  100
#3  42  16  17  18  19  288  323
#4  91  20  20  20  20  400  400
#5 103 103  42  56  84 5768 3528
```

---

If we have lots of columns, then one approach is to `split` the dataset into a `list` of data.frames by taking the substring of names and then loop through the `list` and multiply the rows with `do.call`

```
abc[paste0("new", 1:2)] <- lapply(split.default(abc[-1], 
   sub("\\.[a-z]+$", "", names(abc)[-1])), function(x) do.call(`*`, x))
```

---

Or another option is (based on the pairwise column multiplication)

```
apply(aperm(array(unlist(abc[-1]), c(5, 2, 2)),
            c(3, 1, 2)), 3, matrixStats::colProds)
```

Comment: he wants `1.x` * `1.y` and `2.x` * `2.y`

Comment: I am trying to get a generalized solution where number of columns can be too many. So I want to multiply all x with all y. While x and y are fixed, n has to be figured out from data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Mutate will preserve the original variables. Mutate_all will allow you to multiply all columns in your dataframe.

```
abc %>%
  mutate(new_vary1 = `1.x`* `2.x`,
         new_vary2 = `1.y`* `2.y`) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(.*`1.x`))
```